# docker build: Returned a non-zero code: 2

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This line causes my docker build to fail. It works fine on a clean debian install. What would be the proper way to define this line?

```
RUN debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password s3cr3t'
```

> Step 5 : RUN debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server
>   mysql-server/root_password password s3cr3t'  ---> Running in
>   2309ecbf6f15 /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected The
>   command '/bin/sh -c debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server
>   mysql-server/root_password password s3cr3t"' returned a non-zero code:
>   2

Comment: Example here https://github.com/crashsystems/gitlab-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile `RUN echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $MYSQLTMPROOT | debconf-set-selections`

Comment: Confirmed, this works. Thank you.

Comment: @XiongbingJin, I think you'd better post an answer.